# how to change key and value of object?

Tags: javascript

how to change value of the object to an object contains key:value key:value to all models array
if there any way please share it with me

```
const hello = [
    {
      brand: "Acura",
      models: [
        "2.2CL",
        "2.3CL",
        "3.0CL",
        "3.2CL",
        "ILX",
        "Integra",
        "Legend",
        "MDX",
        "NSX",
        "RDX",
        "3.5 RL",
        "RL",
        "RSX",
        "SLX",
        "2.5TL",
        "3.2TL",
        "TL",
        "TSX",
        "Vigor",
        "ZDX"
      ]
    },
    {
      brand: "Alfa Romeo",
      models: [
        "164",
        "8C Competizione",
        "GTV-6",
        "Milano",
        "Spider"
      ]
    },
    {
      brand: "AMC",
      models: [
        "Alliance",
        "Concord",
        "Eagle",
        "Encore",
        "Spirit"
      ]
    },
```

and make it like this for all models {value:"value", label:"value"},

```
const hello = [
    {
      brand: "Acura",
      models: [
       {value:"2.2CL", label:"2.2CL"},
       {value:"2.3CL", label:"2.3CL"},
       .
```

and make it like this for all models {value:"value", label:"value"},and make it like this for all models {value:"value", label:"value"},and make it like this for all models {value:"value", label:"value"},

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you could do :

```js
const hello = [{
    brand: "Acura",
    models: [
      "2.2CL",
      "2.3CL",
      "3.0CL",
      "3.2CL",
      "ILX",
      "Integra",
      "Legend",
      "MDX",
      "NSX",
      "RDX",
      "3.5 RL",
      "RL",
      "RSX",
      "SLX",
      "2.5TL",
      "3.2TL",
      "TL",
      "TSX",
      "Vigor",
      "ZDX"
    ]
  },
  {
    brand: "Alfa Romeo",
    models: [
      "164",
      "8C Competizione",
      "GTV-6",
      "Milano",
      "Spider"
    ]
  },
  {
    brand: "AMC",
    models: [
      "Alliance",
      "Concord",
      "Eagle",
      "Encore",
      "Spirit"
    ]
  },
];

const result = hello.map(item => {
  return {
    ...item,
    models: item.models.map(val => {
      return {
        value: val,
        label: val
      }
    })
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @amghare - note this answer uses a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)  to simplify the code. +1

Comment: thank you what about if i want also brand to make it like this brand:{value:"bmw",label:"bmw"}

Comment: @Peterrabbit thank you what about if i want also brand to make it like this brand:{value:"bmw",label:"bmw"} –

Comment: @amghare then just add `brand: {value: item.brand, label: item.brand}`, and if there are no other fields than model and brand you can remove the `...item` .

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the best answer, but the map and reduce methods is what you are looking for

```
const result = hello.map((item) => {
  const models = item.models.reduce((acum, curr) => {
    acum.push({
      value: curr,
      label: curr,
    });

    return acum;
  }, []);

  return {
    brand: item.brand,
    models,
  };
});
```